# Unable to add ondrej repository apt in Ubuntu 23.10 Mantic Minotaur

Tags: php, ppa, 23.10

[image: error]

Am I doing something wrong or my Ubuntu version is just not compatible with this repo? If so, from where can I get `php7.4-fpm` package?

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't have 23.10 packages yet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @[R A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1489889/unable-to-add-ondrej-repository-apt-in-ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur/1489893#comment2609816_1489889) said, ondrej's repo doesn't support Ubuntu 23.10, but I would remove the word "yet". **Ubuntu 21.10 Impish Indri was the last non-LTS release supported.**

If you really need to use `php7.4-fpm`, my suggestion is to downgrade to the last LTS version, Ubuntu 22.04.

Here is a quote by **oerdnj** himself from https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1662:

> After some thought, these repositories will not support the non-LTS
> Ubuntu versions. It requires an extra effort to add all the packages
> to the new Ubuntu release, and it does consume computing cycles every
> time there's a new PHP (or any other package updates).
>
> The release cycle on non-LTS Ubuntu release is just 9 months this
> feels like a waste of just everything. There also doesn't seem to be a
> very high demand for these packages - only a handful of people wrote
> here, to mail or on Twitter asking for Ubuntu Impish support.
>
> Ubuntu 21.10 Impish Indri will be the last non-LTS release supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use packages from the latest LTS release:

```
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ jammy main 
deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ jammy main
```

This works on Lunar Lobster (23.04), I have not tried on Mantic Minotaur (23.10) yet.

Comment: This is essentially saying "oh yeah here's a workaround" when Ondrej themselves have said "I don't support non-LTS versions anymore", meaning there's likely to be problems introduced.

Comment: @ThomasWard Yes, Ondrej Sury does not support non-LTS versions. On the other side, a lot of people use non-LTS versions! Yes, it is workaround. Also downgrading to 1.5year old 22.04   can be considered as workaround as well, if you already enjoy fresh Ubuntu/Kubuntu . And he did not said nothing about problems, but about wasting CPU time for some many PHP/Ubuntu versions.

Comment: I will say this is **strongly discouraged** because the libraries, etc. are **newer** in non-LTS releases and that PPA may not properly function if underlying C libraries, etc. are too new and the programs don't work.  That's why for people doing production site deployments it is **strongly recommended** to do LTS-only.  My statement still stands for this reason.

Comment: @ThomasWard, I think everyone understands differences between LTS and non-LTS version and also possible problems with dependencies/versions (e.g. glibc 2.35 vs 2.38). I can confirm 22.04 packages work perfectly on Lunar Lobster (23.04). Someone using non-LTS versions and Ubuntu developers would **strongly disagree** with your "to do LTS-only". It is also a different question, not related to this topic. See https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle, to quote part about non-LTS: "_These are production-quality releases_".

Comment: Working on Mantic Minotaur (23.10), very useful for setting a correct minimal requirement on cross environments project with composer.