# Can not activate php-mysql with MariaDB on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: apache2, php, mariadb, 23.10

I upgraded my Ubuntu to version 23.10. This comes with PHP 8.2. I installed MariaDB and php-mysql extension from standard Ubuntu repository.

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql mariadb-server
```

MariaDB works well through CLI client, but PHP does not communicate with the database.

My local WordPress installations return this error message:

```
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

Please check that the mysqli PHP extension is installed and enabled.
```

I found this info:
PHP 8.2: MySQLi can no longer be compiled with libmysqli
https://php.watch/versions/8.2/mysqli-libmysql-no-longer-supported

Could this be the cause? Is there any way to activate MySQL Native Driver in Ubuntu's PHP 8.2?

Update: temporarily resolved by downgrade to PHP 8.1 from [ppa:ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/).

Comment: The issue you're encountering is indeed related to changes in PHP 8.2, specifically regarding the MySQLi extension. As of PHP 8.2, the MySQLi extension can no longer be compiled with libmysql (the client library for MySQL) and instead requires mysqlnd (MySQL Native Driver). This change means that if your PHP environment or the php-mysql package was compiled with libmysql, it won't work with PHP 8.2.

Comment: Can you edit your question with details how did you install your PHP and the `php-mysql` package? `ppa:ondrej/php` doesn't support non-LTS releases, so it doesn't support Ubuntu 23.10, check this https://askubuntu.com/a/1489893/1157209

Comment: Ok, I removed ppa:ondrej/ph, reinstalled Ubuntu's PHP 8.2 and edited the question with installation details.

Comment: @RobertZelník I just tried running `sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql mariadb-server` on a freshly installed Ubuntu 23.10. The PHP connects to the database without any problems. Can you share more details about your problem? For example, the PHP code you use to connect to the database. A screen shot or exact quote of the error message will be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described works without problems on a clean freshly installed Ubuntu 23.10. It looks like you broke something while experimenting with `ppa:ondrej/php`. [Ondrej's repo only supports LTS releases](https://askubuntu.com/a/1489893/1157209), so it will not work with Ubuntu 23.10.

My suggestion is to do some cleanup and reinstall your PHP and required packages.

1. Remove `ppa:ondrej/php`:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ondrej/php
   ```
2. Remove the PHP:

   ```
   sudo apt purge php*
   sudo apt autoremove
   sudo rm -rf /etc/php/8.2
   sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/php
   ```
3. Install PHP:

   ```
   sudo apt install php php-mysql
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Comment: You are right @sotirov, it was a broken installation. I did a full php* purge and clean install and it is working well now. Thanks for your help.