# Installing PHP 8.1 on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: php, 23.10

After the update to Ubuntu 23.10, my `nginx` (which used `php7.4`) is no longer working. I need to install `php8.1` (or 7.4) in order to update my site.

How do I get PHP 8.1 to install on Ubuntu 23.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 23.10 only have PHP 8.2 in the default repos.

Usually the easiest way to install older PHP versions on Ubuntu is to use ondrej's repo, but [it doesn't support non-LTS releases anymore](https://askubuntu.com/a/1489893/1157209), so in you cases, this will not help.

**My suggestion is to downgrade to last LTS release - Ubuntu 22.04 and install PHP 8.1 there.**

If you really want to use Ubuntu 23.10, you can always build PHP 8.1 from sources but that can be more complex and time consuming.

Comment: Is there a standard way to do the downgrade?  I just upgraded yesterday and had no idea I would need to install older version of PHP once the upgrade was complete.

Comment: @jloper In my opinion, the best way is to backup your data and do a clean install.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I elected to restore the VM from backup and leave the system on Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: @jloper This will temporary fix your problem, just be aware that Ubuntu 23.04 will reach its End of Life on 2024 January 20.