# What PHP version/s will be officially supported by Ubuntu 24.04

Tags: php, 24.04

In a nutshell, I've somehow upgraded from 22.04 to 23.10, and now I cannot have a fully functional PHP 8.1. I won't make a topic about this, I just want to know what PHP will be on Ubuntu 24.04 - can't seem to find many results googling.

Additionally, is there any php 8.1 repository for 23.10?

Cheers.

Comment: Asking questions about unreleased versions of Ubuntu are typically a no-no here but, if you need specific versions of PHP (or any server software), I would strongly recommend using Docker containers. This will allow you to always control the version of PHP (or a database, or Java, etc.) regardless of which version of Ubuntu you are running 

Comment: @matigo this could be borderline. It is not really about a problem in 24.04. and it can be answered with facts ;)

Comment: regarding the 2nd part: 23.10 and 8.1... don't think so. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492816/installing-php-8-1-on-ubuntu-23-10   You should stick to LTS if you want 8.1

Comment: I should have, yes

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04 (*noble*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *noble* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *mantic* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: How can people be *factful* about a non-existing, but in *development* product?  There were features in *mantic* at this stage of *development* that got pulled prior to *mantic* becoming Ubuntu 23.10!  Also tehre were features in not yet in *lunar* that were not expected in the release, but then got pushed very late in the cycle & added via SRU at this stage. Whilst SRU type changes are far less likely on a LTS, they still can happen (and *development* hasn't met *freeze* and FFE or SRU's aren't yet required!)

Comment: Added for clarity...  After *feature freeze* all parts of the *unreleased* product should be predictable; however FFe or *Feature Freeze Exceptions* can still be made causing the *known* to change. At a later stage (post-beta) where the system is frozen except for bug fixes; SRU or *Stable Release Updates* (a higher level than FFE) can still cause change, after all the product even after *beta* still hasn't released as a *stable* product, so the *treating it as if its stable* is more *intent* at that somewhat *late* stage (*stable* is only *really* met when it's at ~RC/Release Candidate*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP version for Ubuntu 24.04 will be 8.3. It will not be 8.2, despite what https://packages.ubuntu.com/ says. Ubuntu 24.04 has not been released, so the current version likely reflects the release of 23.10, not what's planned for 24.04.

You can see what versions of major packages are planned at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649 . It clearly says "13     January 18  PHP 8.3 transtion [sic]".

Comment: Related: https://slickstack.io/forum/topic/official-php-version-for-ubuntu-24-04-lts-release

Answer (score 0):

https://packages.ubuntu.com  has all the version numbers. PHP is going to be 8.2.

```
noble (php): server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (default)
2:8.2+93ubuntu1: all
also provides by: php8.2, uwsgi-plugin-php
```

Comment: yeah, got it https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/php/php

Comment: This has been updated and now includes PHP 8.3